# teleop + Collision detection

Tags: ros, navigation, collision, costmap, teleop

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What is the most effective way to implement teleop (twist) with collision detection, basically how to query the costmap to determine if is clear of free to send the twist msg ?

Cheers,
Tiago

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213495/teleop-+-collision-detection/) by [P Tiago P](https://answers.ros.org/users/20281/p-tiago-p/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-07-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [navigation_collision_checker_node](https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/navigation_collision_checker/blob/master/src/navigation_collision_checker_node.cpp) is a straightforward implementation of using MoveIt! collision checking against an octomap to prevent collisions with the environment. It takes in a Octomap on a topic as well as a Twist and sets output Twist to zero in case a collision is predicted. There's a lot of fancy stuff that could be done on top, but it works ok.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2015-07-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Schould look at the code from [Ros-Wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/cob_collision_velocity_filter)

---

Originally posted by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) with karma: 1999 on 2015-07-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1